# Is to + ing (to becoming) correct?

Tags: grammar

I have read in a newspaper, the writer is using 'to becoming'.

eg: "We're on track to becoming developed nation."

Is this sentence really correct?

Comment: Good question. But we usually don't ask for help through e-mail here: other readers might benefit from the answers too! I have removed your address—I hope you will forgive me.

Comment: I don't know if rep is required, but you can check the option to be notified daily on new answers.

Answer (score 11):

It would have to be *to becoming **a** developed nation*.

To clarify, the reason is that in this sentence, "to" is being used not as part of an infinitive (like "to talk," for example). It's a simple preposition; the sentence could be recast into something like "We're getting closer to the state of being a developed nation."

Comment: It might help to think of *becoming a developed nation* as a place, like London. It's a similar construction.

Comment: Another big clue that this is what's going on is that you can do "nouny" things with *becoming*, such as adding a possessive: "I look forward to *our* becoming a developed nation".

Answer (score 4):

The main issue here is that there are two main forms of the *on track…* phrase, one taking a noun (with *for*), one taking an infinitive:

> We’re on track for our development goals next year.

> We’re on track to reach our development goals next year.

The first of these, the *for* form, can be used with any noun phrase, so in particular works fine with a [gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund):

> We’re on track for reaching our development goals next year.

(‘Gerund’ means that *reaching…* here is acting as a noun phrase.  Compare, for instance, “Reaching our development goals will be wonderful!”)

The main problem with the example you give is that *becoming* is a gerund, so *becoming a developed county* acts as a noun phrase, but *on track to* isn’t usually used with noun phrases — *on track for* is much more common.  So you would not usually write or say either of:

> ?We’re on track to our development goals next year

> ?We’re on track to reaching our development goals next year.

In general, though, *to* is fine with a gerund, anywhere you could use *to* with a noun phrase:

> We’re very close to reaching our development goals.

[There’s also a second, unrelated, much simpler issue in your sentence: it should be *“becoming **a** developed nation.”*]

Comment: The problem with this answer is that (at least according to [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+track+to+being%2C+on+track+for+being%2C+on+track+to+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20track%20to%20being%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20track%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0)) people don't use *"on track for"* with gerunds. I've checked this with several verbs, and none of them registered on Ngrams. I don't think it's ungrammatical; just unidiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

The expression "be on track + to ..." is more likely to appear in writings however the example given here (and very common form in conversation) implies a slightly different meaning: 
"We're on track to becom**ing** **a** developed nation." means we are making progress and (The writer thinks and evidence shows) that we are going to start the path which leads to a developed nation "or" we are going to start becoming + a developed nation.